# Transposing only specific columns to reshape Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv having data like :

[image]

I want only the last two columns to be somewhat like transposed like below :

[image]

Im using pandas to read in the csv and what the output dataframe to be as above.

Im not sure if we can pivot only specific columns as I want this only applied to last two columns , also I think pivot kind of aggregates the data under same column which i dont want.

Comment: Use `df1 = df.set_index(['A','B','C','D'])['E'].unstack().reset_index()`

Comment: This is not at all a transpose, use group by with `pivot` or `unstack`

Comment: @jezrael I used your solution but it is giving wrong results for A , though not the structure is correct. EG: My 'A' column has one of the value as 1020, but i can see 20 in the output.

Comment: Can we achieve the same with melt ?

Comment: @jezrael  Can you help me with with how to reverse the same now